# Difference in minutes between 2 dates and times?

Tags: date, datetime, abap

I need to compute time difference in minutes with four input parameters, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, TIME_FROM, TIME_TO. And one output parameter DIFF_TIME. I have created a function module, I need to write a formula which computes the time diff in minutes.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,
Sai.

Comment: does http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb334a358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm, help ?

Comment: No not really, this link explains time difference only....will try once...Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are guaranteed to be in the same time zone, it's easy enough that you don't need any special function module or utility method. Read [this](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_snc700_ehp01/helpdata/en/fc/eb334a358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm?no_cache=true), then get the difference of the dates and multiply that by 24 * 60 and get the difference of the times (which is in seconds) and divide that by 60. Sum it up and there you are.

Comment: Original link is broken, internet archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140215024506/http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb334a358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm

Answer (score 7):

Use [**`CL_ABAP_TSTMP=>TD_SUBTRACT`**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_tstmp.htm) to get the number of seconds between two date/time pairs.

(then, to get the number of minutes, divide the number of seconds by 60).

Example:

```
DATA(today_date) = CONV d( '20190704' ).
DATA(today_time) = CONV t( '000010' ).
DATA(yesterday_date) = CONV d( '20190703' ).
DATA(yesterday_time) = CONV t( '235950' ).

cl_abap_tstmp=>td_subtract(
  EXPORTING
    date1    = today_date
    time1    = today_time
    date2    = yesterday_date
    time2    = yesterday_time
  IMPORTING
    res_secs = DATA(diff) ).

ASSERT diff = 20. " verify expectation or short dump
```